# What happened to Windows Based Application in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot find window-based application on XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005546/cannot-find-window-based-application-on-xcode)

I am pretty new to IOS development and have started reading books to help me out.  I only started recently and the books all start you on a windows based application and I see that this does not exist in xcode 4.2.  I have read and found that the way to go is to create an empty project but this does not create a .xib file and I have no idea what I'm doing so it might not seem like a big deal to an experienced IOS developer but this was a huge curve ball for me.  Also there is a bunch more code in the .h and .m file that wasn't there before.  Can someone tell me why this was taken out and maybe sort of guide me to what I should do or what I should start reading.  I know that this may seem like a question that could be solved with a bit more research but the problem is not as much that the windows based app is not there anymore but why is it not there.  Maybe I shouldn't even try and create one anymore?  I have even read posts where they say how to add the .xib file but that didn't really help because when i built my app, it was a blank screen.  Anyways, that's a different problem.

Comment: Actually it's not because I was more curious as to why the windows based application was taken out and suggestions on how to resolve it.  I also knew that a empty project is now the solution and was wanting a bit more detail.  The post that you linked to only says to used an empty application

Comment: @Pitfall - As explained there, it wasn't really taken out, just renamed.  The Xcode templates are just rudimentary starting points, and any of them can be created from one of the others.  As for why templates change, only the Xcode team at Apple could explain the reasoning behind that, not us.  In other words, don't worry about the templates themselves, because any decent book, tutorial, or other resource will show you how a basic application is structured and how to do things like add Interface Builder files to your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are new editions of many beginner books out there, such as the Apress [series](http://www.apress.com/9781430236054)

There is a [walkthrough](http://brianreiter.org/2011/11/23/how-to-create-an-xcode-4-0-style-window-based-application-in-xcode-4-2/) of hooking up a XIB to the empty app which should make it fairly easy to go through the book you already have.  If you're having problems with this though, then I really do recommend the book.  I've gone through the last version of it and I found it very easy to follow and understand.

As for why Apple changed it, as per usual they haven't said anything about what motivates them.  We developers are just left to assume that they must have it in for us.

Answer (score 0):

How to make window-based app in 4.2: http://www.makebetterthings.com/iphone/where-is-mainwindow-xib-in-xcode-4-2/
Make sure you didn't miss "select MainWindow as the Main Interface" part.

Comment: I have seen this post and I think that I was missing the select MainWindow which solves my problem of why I wasn't displaying anything but why was the windows based app taken out?  What was apple's intention?

Comment: ok thanks Kreiri and sanjamal, that was what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Windows Based application are not there in Xcode 4.2. But You can go with option "Empty Applicaion" and manually add Xibs and classes.

For more details please follow this question ["Cannot find window-based application on XCode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005546/cannot-find-window-based-application-on-xcode) where you will find your answer in a more clear way.