# What is the difference between storyboard and pageControl?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

What is the difference between storyboard and pageControl as page controller also presenting sequence of view controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page control adds multiple views inside a scroll view, with paging enabled, the user can scroll from one page to anther, you can add as many pages as you want in the page control,
What really happens is that you will create a very wide scroll view that will contains all your views.

"Storyboards allow you to map out, visually, all of the views in your applications and how they interrelate. If you are just starting out with storyboards, there's an introduction to storyboards in the WWDC 2011 videos https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/"

Quoted from [What is the difference between a .xib file and a .storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436324/what-is-the-difference-between-a-xib-file-and-a-storyboard)

So story board and UIPageControl are not similar at all.