# Where is my .xib file in xcode 4.3.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am a new programming in xcode and I am following a few tutorials on developing programs for iphone. I just got started and I am already lost. I am attempting to work with the built in interface builder and all of my tutorials say to click on my <.projectname>.xib to start editing, but I have no clue where to find this file. I know it used to be found in the resources folder but now that does not exist either. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the image at this point remove the tick mark in `Use StoryBoards` and create a project you can find xib file in your project
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you have created new project with storyboard.

If you want to use xib, try to recreate project and uncheck "Use storyboard" mark

Answer (score 0):

Are you are using storybord or Empty Application? If so you will not see xib. Select **New Project -> Application -> SingleView Application** and you will see here .xib file. :)

Answer (score 0):

xib (Xcode Interface Builder) files were used in pre-iOS5 era. Concept of `Storyboard` was introduced in iOS 5. Earlier every `UIViewController` used to have an associated `.xib` with it but now `storyboard` manages all the views/screens of an application. (Multiple storyboards can be used.)

You can still use `.xib` approach by not selecting `Use Storyboards` checkbox as shown in image in one of the answers but that would be like washing your clothes with hand in washing-machine era.
You may want to read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436324/what-is-the-difference-between-a-xib-file-and-a-storyboard).

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to resolve any connection issues and have noticed that you need to edit a XIB file but have selected the `Use Storyboards` option when creating your project, simply right-click the `Main.storyboard` > click `Open As` > then click `Source Code`.

This way you don't have to recreate the project from scratch.

[image: Screenshot of how it appears on my end, as of July 2018]